# Changing the view - Sencha

Tags: navigation, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I want to change view on itemtap and i have done that

```
itemtap : function(list, index, target, record, event) {
 var id = index + 1;
if(id == '1'){
Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true);  
Ext.Viewport.add([

 { xtype: 'publishedword' }

 ]);  
}
```

now,
I am trying it to apply in view as shown in below pic where 1st view contains an Menu with populated item and now onclick of those item I want to open new view in Homepage replacing HomePage View.
How can i achieve this?

Container for below pic:

```
 Ext.define('myprj.view.Main', {
 extend: 'Ext.Container',
 alias: 'widget.mainmenuview',

 config: {

 width: 710,
 margin: '10px auto 0',
 layout: {
 type: 'hbox'
 },
defaults: {
  flex: 1
},
activeItem: 1,
items: [{
flex: 1,
xtype: 'container',
cls:'wholeMenuWrap',
margin: '65px 0 0 0',
width: 170,
layout: 'vbox', 

  items: [
  {
    xtype:'menupage',
    cls: 'menuPage',
    docked: 'left',    
  },
   {
    xtype:'homepage',
    cls: 'homePage', 
    //docked: 'center',
  },

  {
    xtype:'categorypage',
    cls: 'categoryPage',
    docked: 'right',
  },]
}]
}
});
```

Now in the above code i only want to change homepage and display another view with respect to itemtap.
![firstscreen][1]
And when i use above code for this situation whole view is changed but i just want to change 2nd view with respect to itemTap.
Thank You.

**EDITED**

```
  if(id == '1'){
console.log("Value of Click--"+id);
var publishedword = { xtype: 'publishedword' }; 

   // I am assuming active item is container, here i am getting Container object
   var outerContainer = Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(1);

   // removing the second item (index start with 0) 
   outerContainer.down('panel').removeAt(1);

   // replacing second item into publishedword
   outerContainer.down('panel').insert(1, publishedword);
   outerContainer.getAt(1).setActiveItem(publishedword);
  }
```

After this code i am able to load published word as shown in below picture![result2][2]
Now i want is My Words to be in between Menu and categories. In the above picture you can see homepage is not destroyed it's coming in back of published word.

Comment: what do you mean whole view ? or what are the components within that whole view ?

Comment: whole view means outer rectangle.

Comment: ok, is that outer rectangle is a panel or what type of component ?

Comment: do you want to replace second view into publishedword view ?

Comment: home page is coming below Menu but i want to replace second view (published words ) into homepage.

Comment: @Viswa Can you check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987054/old-view-appears-in-background?lq=1. Thank you for your Help

Comment: i answered based on what i understood.. it's good.. you solved your problem.

Comment: thanks for the help. Your help made possible to tackle problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This what your doing, but there are things you need to understand

```
    itemtap : function(list, index, target, record, event) {
     var id = index + 1;
     if(id == '1'){

        //This line will remove the whole container, but that's not you want
        Ext.Viewport.remove(Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem(), true); 

        //This line will add publishedword conponent into viewport not carousel
        Ext.Viewport.add({ xtype: 'publishedword' });  
     }
   }
```

What you need to do is

```
    itemtap : function(list, index, target, record, event) {
     var id = index + 1;
     if(id == '1'){
       var publishedword = { xtype: 'publishedword' }; 

       // I am assuming active item is container, here i am getting Container object
       var outerContainer = Ext.Viewport.getActiveItem();

       // removing the second item (index start with 0) 
       outerContainer.down('carousel').removeAt(1);

       // replacing second item into publishedword
       outerContainer.down('carousel').insert(1, publishedword);
     }
   }
```

Comment: your way is working but i am unable set homepage in the center

Comment: what you mean "in the center" ?

Comment: can you tell me in what order those views displaying ?

Comment: menu->homepage->categories and homepage is always in center only that view changes in itemTap. And i pasted wrong code at first it's panel not carousel you can have a look onto my edited code. Thank You.

Comment: I'm having hard time understanding you

Comment: What can i do to make you understand?

Comment: update question with latest code (with changes you did after my answer)

Answer (score 1):

You could make your Homepage component behave like `Ext.Viewport`.

From the docs:

> Ext.Viewport is a instance created when you use Ext.setup. Because
>   Ext.Viewport extends from Ext.Container, it has as layout (which
>   defaults to Ext.layout.Card). This means you can add items to it at
>   any time, from anywhere in your code. The Ext.Viewport fullscreen
>   configuration is true by default, so it will take up your whole
>   screen.

You basically have to give Homepage a `layout: 'card'`. Then you can add views to it like it was the main Viewport.

[EDIT] Give your homepage container an id for convenience:

```
{
    id: 'homepage',
    xtype:'homepage',
    cls: 'homePage',
    //docked: 'center',
    layout: 'card'
},

var view = Ext.getCmp("viewId");          // replace this code with the code to
                                          // get the view you actually want
                                          // to add

var homepage = Ext.getCmp("homepage");    // get it by the id we set before
homepage.animateActiveItem(view, 'fade'); // you can animate a transition
homepage.add(view);                       // or just add it
```

[EDIT] You can also add instantiating on the fly like you were doing before:

```
homepage.add([
    { xtype: 'publishedword' }
]);
```

Comment: encountered: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'animateActiveItem' of undefined

Comment: My code it's not meant to work by copy paste, try to understand what I mean and customize for your case. Anyway, I edited to show you how to give an id to your component.

Comment: i removed this code homepage.animateActiveItem(view, 'fade'); and it worked. Since i have already accepted answer upvoted you

Comment: I don't want you to change the accepted answer if you think that @Viswa one is better; but just for your information, if you want to change answer because a better one comes at a later time you can do it.